# Console error for jQuery/Ajax contact form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've the following error when trying to set up a contact form using Ajax:

```
send
v.extend.ajax
(anonymous function)
v.event.dispatch
o.handle.u
```

[Link to live site](http://ppplasmaltd.co.uk/contact-ppplasma)

jQuery

```
( function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#get-contact-form").submit(function() {

            var str = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://ppplasmaltd.co.uk/templates/plasma/html/com_contact/contact/contact-form-process.php",
                data: str,
                success: function(msg) {

                    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {

                    if (msg === 'OK') {
                        result = '<div class="thanks" id="thanks">Thank you, we will reply <span>shortly.</span></div>';

                    else
                    {
                        result = msg;
                    }

                    });
                }
            });
        return false;
        });
    });
} ) ( jQuery );
```

Any help on how to resolve this would be great....

I'm fairly new to jQuery/Ajax.

Comment: Its 500 internal server error, error is on server side code. try to debug it on you php code base.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to place `ajaxComplete` inside your `success` callback of `$.ajax()`. You also have a missing closing brace (`}`).

Try the following:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#get-contact-form").submit(function() {
            var str = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://ppplasmaltd.co.uk/templates/plasma/html/com_contact/contact/contact-form-process.php",
                data: str,
                success: function(msg) {

                    if (msg === 'OK')
                    {
                        result = '<div class="thanks" id="thanks">Thank you, we will reply <span>shortly.</span></div>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = msg;
                    }
                }
            });
        return false;
        });
    });
}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: cheers for the help, I wasn't aware ajaxComplete is not required. There was an issue with my server side code as well

Comment: Glad to help. You might want to accept the answer if it helped ;)